# How to marshal to JSON/XML when an exception occurs with Camel rest-dsl

Tags: json, rest, apache-camel, marshalling

I have a REST-dsl camel route with binding: json_xml
with .type() and outType(). It works perfectly when no exception occurs. That is json input gives json output. Xml input gives xml output.

However, when I get an IllegalArgumentException I always return XML. I create a ErrorResponse POJO when the exception occurs. The CONTENT_TYPE is set to "application/json" for json. How do I return a POJO and let camel marhal to JSON/XML when an Exception occurs(given ResBindingMode.json_xml)?

```
onException(IllegalArgumentException.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, LOGGER, "error")
        .handled(true)
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(400))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, exchangeProperty(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE))
        .bean(errorResponseTranslator);
restConfiguration().component("restlet").port(port).skipBindingOnErrorCode(true)
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json_xml);
    rest("/whatever/api/v1/request")
        .post().type(RequestDto.class).outType(ResponseDto.class)
            .route()
            .setProperty(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, header(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE))
           ...process
```

ErrorDto:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "errorResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class ErrorResponseDto {
  private String errorCode;
  private String message;

  @XmlElement(name = "message")
  public String getMessage() {
      return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "errorCode")
  public String getErrorCode() {
      return errorCode;
  }

  public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
      this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the outType not dynamic. It seems like its a camel bug. That is: the outType must be an XMLROOT that contains OK and ERROR dto. It is possible to quickfix this if you use a XMLroot that takes an any element with lax=true(here you can add the ErrorDto or okResponseDto). But it does add an unwanted element. For now we have to implement a custom contentNegotiator.

This is when using skipBindingOnError is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type explicit to XML then

```
 .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, exchangeProperty(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE))
```

Should be

```
 .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
```

Comment: I tried it, still gives xml with Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
when use  .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json")). Camel bug?

Comment: .. the response is in XML format and the header on the response is Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Comment: You need to set skipBindingOnErrorCode=false, see more details at http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl

Comment: I tried setting skipBindingOnErrorCode=false It can only produce custom JSON errorResponse. When I should produce a XML errorResponse I get the following error: InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement but has value: no.name.dto.response.ErrorResponseDto@3c3a808 Even though it has @XmlRootElement. It seems to be because the jaxbContext class is set on ResponseDto because of the skipBindingOnErrorCode=false option. How do I solve this?

Comment: I also tried to wrap the ErrorResponse POJO in a JaxbElement(for XML) but got the following error:java.io.IOException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException ........
 Cause: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: no.name.dto.response.ErrorResponseDto is not known to this context